Change of Variables Question. Difference in Notation.
My textbook has an example where it uses $\frac{dy}{dx} dx = dy$ in an indefinite integral.
Change of Variable example
I'm rusty on my calculus, can anyone explain to me why this is?
My understanding is that $y(x)$ IS the function that is being substituted but I think my confusion is that the CoV formula is in a different notation. Can someone explain / connect to the notations between the formula and this example? And what would the formula be in Leibniz Notation?
Change of Variable Formula

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

$\frac{dy}{dx}dx$ is equal to $dy$ by the chain rule. The substitution feels unnecessary in this case.

In the example, $y = g(x)$ and $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ is simply Leibniz notation for $g'(x)$.
So when we write
$$ \int f'(y) \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\, \mathrm dx = \int f'(y) \, \mathrm dy \tag1 $$
it's exactly the same as writing
$$ \int f'(g(x)) g'(x) \, \mathrm dx = \int f'(y) \, \mathrm dy. \tag2 $$
So Equation $(1)$ is how you write the change of variables formula in Leibniz notation.
Why use Leibniz notation in the example? Perhaps because the example started with a differential equation written in Leibniz notation.

The $\frac{dy}{dx}dx=dy$ is simply the chain rule but I am not sure why your book did that as it seems like overkill. A lot of times you will see the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ notation abused and treated like a fraction. This would lead to:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-xy$$
$$\frac1y\,dy=-x\,dx$$
I am not going to encourage this abuse of notation, but I think it is helpful to see it written this way.
As for the formula you attached, it is a formula for integration by substitution. This method of integration is counterpart to the chain rule and can kind of be thought of as doing the chain rule backwards.

So is $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ not a ratio of $2$ infinitesimal quantities?
